# My netlify app won't displays a blank white screen on some devices but fine on others

Tags: hosting, netlify

My recently deployed netlify app shows a blank white page when visited by certain people but displays and functions just fine on other devices regardless of browsers.

I really don't know how to approach this problem, I've tried it across several browsers on my phone and computer and found no problems. But some of my friends are reporting a blank white screen when the visit the same address. The app was created using Reactjs. how do I fix this pls?

Site domain name is https://bootlegga.com

Comment: It seems to work fine for me! Its a little slow, nothing else!

Comment: Its the same for me, but these people weren't lying, they send screenshots @Manas Khandelwi

Comment: Netlify is very reputed. Try contacting them!

Comment: I"m doing that right now. I trying to get help in the support forum